# Plot connects all data points instead of line

Tags: data-visualization, matlab

I am training ANN and I want to plot the results - so I can see if the model predicts the data correctly:

My code:

```
%-----DATA SET-----
x=0:0.08:6*pi;
y=sin(x);
%create noise
a = -.3; b = .3; 
noise = a + (b-a) * rand(1,length(y)); 
%add noise
y_n=y+noise;

%-----SPLIT INTO TRAIN AND TEST-----
p=x;t=y_n;
num = size(p,2);
split_point = round(num*0.7);
seq = randperm(num);
p_train = p(:,seq(1:split_point));
t_train = t(seq(1:split_point));
p_test = p(:,seq(split_point+1:end));
t_test = t(seq(split_point+1:end));

%-----ANN-----
net=newff([0 6*pi],[5 1],{'tansig','purelin'},'traingd','learnp');
net.trainParam.epochs=500; %number of epochs
net=train(net,p_train,t_train); % batch training
output=sim(net,p_test);
%plot ANN
scatter(x, y_n,'x');
hold on;
scatter(p_test,output,'o');
```

This is my result:
[image]

But I would like to have **one smooth line**. If I do `plot(p_test,output)` all data points get connected like this:

[image]

I suppose I have `output` in wrong format, but I cannot figure out how to do it properly.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: what would the line plot look like if you were first to sort the points by their x-values?

Comment: Like this? `plot(sort(p_test),output);`? Not, I expect the line be same as the dots on my first example. And this is not the case.

Comment: You need to sort the *points*, not just their x coordinates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to sort your x and y values appropriately.
If you do that the plot looks fine. Please see the follow snippet with an example on how to do this.

```
%plot ANN
scatter(x, y_n,'x');
hold on;
scatter(p_test,output,'o'); 
[ia,ib] = sort(p_test);
plot(ia,output(ib),'k-');
```